# Rails 4 w/ Geocoder Get IP address during form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-geocoder

I have installed the Geocoder Gem and when a user submits a form, I want to use their IP address to automatically submit their lat/lon to my database.  I am having a hard time finding a tutorial for this.  Everything I'm finding is either using c/s/c submission or trying to find distances using IP address which isn't what I want.  Eventually I want to take the lat/lon and use them to show where the user was when they submitted the form both on their user profile and on a google map but for now I just want to save them.

With the following setup, I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in AnswersController#create
undefined method `ip_address' for #<Answer:0x007fc1cd589968>
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= form_for [@daily, @answer] do |answer| %>
  <%= answer.label :answer, "" %>
  <%= answer.text_area :answer %><br>

  <%= answer.label :tags, "Tags (separate by commas, use '-' with multi-word tags"%>
  <%= answer.text_field :tag_list %><br>

  <%= answer.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my answers controller:

```
  def new
    @daily = Question.find_by(show_month: Time.now.month, show_day: Time.now.day)
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
    @answer = Answer.new( answer_params )
    @answer.user_id = current_user.id
    @answer.question_id = @question.id
    if @answer.save
      redirect_to @question
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:answer, :user_id, :question_id, :tag_list, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
```

my answer model:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_taggable
  geocoded_by :ip_address
  after_validation :geocode
end
```

I also found this helper method to use during development (since localhost wont provide an IP)

```
def location
  if params[:location].blank?
    if Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?
      @location ||= Geocoder.search("50.78.167.161").first
    else
      @location ||= request.location
    end
  else
    params[:location].each {|l| l = l.to_i } if params[:location].is_a? Array
    @location ||= Geocoder.search(params[:location]).first
    @location
  end
end
```

I think I need to add

```
result = request.location
```

but I don't know where. I tried adding it to the AnswersController but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: I did that. Now I am getting "NoMethodError in AnswersController#create
undefined method `ip_address' for #<Answer:0x007fc1cd589968>"

Comment: Does Answer have an ip_address field?

Comment: You mean the table?  No, it has space for lat and lon which is how the gem set it up.